# Where do I replace mozimageSmoothingEnabled to imageSmoothingEnabled

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a very simple HTML/Js code that is supposed to draw a simple circle on a canvas.

```js
const canvas=
document.querySelector('#canvas1');
const ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

class Particule{
    constructor(x, y, dirX, dirY, taille, coul){
        this.x= x;
        this.y= y;
        this.dirX= dirX;
        this.dirY= dirY;
        this.taille= taille;
        this.coul= coul;
    }
    dessine(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.taille, 0,
            Math.pi * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle= this.coul;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

const ob= new Particule(10, 10, 50, 50, 100, "white");
ob.dessine();
console.log(ob);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Particles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1">
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is supposed to output a white circle on the top left corner of the screen but when I launch it, just the dark grey background appears even though there is no error logs on the console.
On Firefox, the is a warning saying

> Use of mozImageSmoothingEnabled is deprecated. Please use the
> unprefixed imageSmoothingEnabled property instead.

and I think it 'may' be the reason why things are not working.
The problem is I DON'T have `mozImageSmoothingEnabled` or `ImageSmoothingEnabled`  anywhere in my code. I didn't even use it in the first place so how would I be able to replace it?

I am using the latest version of Firefox and I couldn't find any help about this anywhere.

If anyone can indicate me how could I fix this, it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a typo in `arc` arguments, should be `Math.PI`. I can't reproduce the warning, though.

Comment: About the warning, do you use any third-party library which draws to a canvas, something not shown here?

Comment: Wow. Thank you. And when I use `Math.PI` there is no more warning for some reason. Thank you

Comment: Now I'm amazed, I didn't get the warning with your original code.

Comment: I don't use any third-party libraries here. I figure it sould be coming from some script some where but this is the only script I use so I guess it's some bug in Firefox. Anyway the warning is gone when I corrected the misspell. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Math.PI instead of Math.pi bro ^_^[image: Your code with Math.PI]

## Advices

- Use a modern IDE/Code editor that will be help you with this little errors.
- Use debugger to what values use computer. If you create breakpoint at the start and see step by step all your values in code you see that problem is in Math.pi

Comment: Yes, I already corrected it out as @Teemu pointed out in the comments..

Comment: The thing is that, usually, each time the code contains an error like this, it would pop-up as an undefined variable in the browser console and this didn't show any error log in any browser, I just got that weird warning instead. Thanks anyway !

Comment: This error related only to firefox, other browsers work without this error, So I would recommend you to not write a big code, try to check if your code works every little block of code, and use debugger :)